# Does the damage of the Overseer's Guardian include one bullet or both?

Tags: fallout-4

For example, I have the calibrated power receiver on my Overseer's Guardian, and it does about 140 damage. Since it fires two bullets each time the trigger is pulled, does each bullet do about 70 damage for a total of 140, or does each bullet do about 140 damage, coming out to 280 damage a pop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_weapon_effects) does a good job at explaining the math behind all Two-Shot weapons:

> The game adds the base (i.e. unmodded) damage of the gun to its current (modded) damage and then splits the combined damage evenly into two projectiles. For example, an unmodded Hunting rifle does 37 damage, while a .50 cal Hunting rifle does 64. So a Two-shot .50 cal Hunting rifle does 64+37 = 101 damage, resulting in two projectiles hitting for 50.5 each. The damage value displayed in the Pip-Boy is the damage of both projectiles combined.

It looks like the second bullet fired only does its base (unmodified) damage.  From what I can gather, the base damage of the [Overseer's Guardian](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Overseer's_Guardian) is 55.  So in your case, it should be 140+55 to get you 195 damage total or 97.5 damage for each bullet.

Comment: But note that even though it shoots two bullets, defenses are only applied once, so you do not have doubled defenses with the Two Shot effect.